# Temporarily Disabling Gold Linker on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying out the Gold Linker to see if it will improve link time of our application.  And it does, significantly.  Occasionally, I need to use the GNU Linker.  How would I go about doing this?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and I installed the Gold Linker from the package manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

/usr/bin/ld is just a symlink to whichever your actual linker is. Check to make sure that /usr/bin/ld on your system is just a symlink to ld.gold. If it is, then you can just do ln -sf ld.bfd /usr/bin/ld